# Able to access webcam, Unable to show video

Tags: html, django-templates, webcam

The webcam green light was on when I implement the code, but the cam window didn't come out, instead, the "Could not access the camera. Error: TypeError" kept coming out...... Are there any bugs in my code?

```
    if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
  // access the web cam
  const constraints =  {video:true, audio:false} 
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    // permission granted:
    .then(function(stream) {
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.addEventListener('click', takeSnapshot);
    })
    // permission denied:
    .catch(function(error) {
      document.body.textContent = 'Could not access the camera. Error: ' + error.name;
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem turns out that my browser was updated causing the code `video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);` to crush. Just change that line to `video.srcObject = stream;` and it works just fine.